# Does there exist an entire function with $f(0)=1$ and $f(4i)=i$ and $|f(z_1) - f(z_2)| < |z_1 - z_2|^{\frac{\pi}{3}}$ in $1<|z|<3$?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Does there exist an entire function with $f(0)=1$ and $f(4i)=i$ and $|f(z_1) - f(z_2)| < |z_1 - z_2|^{\frac{\pi}{3}}$ whenever $z_1,z_2 \in \{z: 1<|z|<3\}$?
I think it has something to do with the Maximum-modulus principle or Liouville's theorem. I don't know where to start! If not answer, little hint will also be appreciated.

Comment: $\pi >3$ so the derivative of $f$ is zero in the given annulus

Comment: Thank you so much. So let me complete the argument: $\frac{|f(z_1)-f(z_2)|}{|z_1 - z_2|} < |z_1 - z_2|^{[\frac{\pi}{3}]-1} \rightarrow 0$ as $z_1 \rightarrow z_2$. So, by analytic continuation, $f(z)= constant$ on $\mathbb{C}$. Contradicting the fact that $f(0)=1$ and $f(4i)=i$.

Comment: Correct - in general a non constant function in a connected domain cannot have a Lipschitz (also called Holder) exponent greater than 1